# .NET Month Picker Control

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there a winforms month-only picker control?
I need to allow the user to select the month regardless of the day of the month.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any such control.  You could add the months to a Listbox or Combobox and have them that way?

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, a month-names ComboBox in three lines:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames
        .Where(m => m != String.Empty)
        .Select((m, i) => new { Name = m, Index = i })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => x.Name),
    null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Now `comboBox1.SelectedValue` will be 0..11 depdending on the month selected.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies.

Well, the fun part is that the month should be selected along with the year.

Like: september 2007 or january 2010, etc.

Sorry for not being very clear on that.
Of course, a listbox or combobox can also be adapted for my needs, but I would imagine the control being more like the DateTimePicker, that is, more user-friendly.

Comment: @Matt What about year?

Comment: System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames
                    .Where(m => m != string.Empty)
                    .Select((m, i) => new { Name = m, Index = i })
                    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(2000, 20).Select(y => new { x.Name, x.Index, Year = y }))
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Year * 100 + x.Index, x => x.Name + " " + x.Year);

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such standard control but I it easy to make it on you own , add all months to Drop Down control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTimePicker` with custom format to enable just the month to be specified as following:

```
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM"; // for May, June, July etc. format
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true; // prevents the calendar from being displayed
```